# Monkey patching Python Property setters (and getters?)

Tags: python, monkeypatching

So, monkey patching is pretty awesome, but what if I want to monkey patch a `@property`?

For example, to monkey patch a method:

```
def new_method():
    print('do stuff')
SomeClass.some_method = new_method
```

however, properties in python re-write the = sign.

Quick example, lets say I want to modify x to be 4. How would I go about doing that?:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = 3

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        if value != 3:
            print('Nice try')
        else:
            self.__x = value

foo = MyClass()
foo.x = 4
print(foo.x)
foo.__x = 4
print(foo.x)
```

> Nice try
>
> 3
>
> 3

Comment: The question as-asked doesn't have anything to do with properties, but everything to do with name-mangling due to the double-underscore private variable `self.__x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `_ClassName__attribute`, you can access the attribute:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.__x = 3
...     @property
...     def x(self):
...         return self.__x
...     @x.setter
...     def x(self, value):
...         if value != 3:
...             print('Nice try')
...         else:
...             self.__x = value
... 
>>> foo = MyClass()
>>> foo._MyClass__x = 4
>>> foo.x
4
```

See [Private Variables and Class-local References - Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references), especially parts that mention about *name mangling*.